# Azure throws error when making an axios http request in node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, http, azure-web-app-service

I created a node application using express and uploaded it to an Azure web application. Whenever I send a response like

```js
router.get("/search=:search", (req, res) => res.send("Response"));
```

The API works fine and I get the response, but I included axios to make http requests such as:

```js
const http = require("axios");

const url = "https://yts.torrentbay.to/api/v2/list_movies.jsonp?query_term=shrek";

router.get("/search=:search", async (req, res) => {
  await http.get(url);
  res.send("Response")
});
```

Now this works perfectly on my local machine when testing but Azure throws a `500 Internal Server Error`.
Should I use the built-in http library in node? Could the problem be where the request is made to the URL?

EDIT:
I discovered that the problem is with the URL. I tried `google.com` and it worked so how could I fix this?

Comment: it's possible ...check if app service is running the same node version as you. Otherwise, use a container where you'll have control over it.

Comment: I saw that the problem was the URL, but I have tried hosting it on a server in a different location but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- if you want  the api to work with the wrong url then one of the work around is to add a catch block(error handling )
- you are getting this error because  the `http.get` is not getting any response and it is waiting for a long time.
- You can add a catch block which will get triggered when the `http.get` fails to get a response.
- Inside the catch you can then add a response thus even if you don't get response in `http.get` you get a response from your own Api.

```
router.get("/search=:search", async (req, res) => {
    await  http.get(url).catch((err)=>{
                                          res.send("error has happend ");
                                      });
    res.send("Response");
});
```